# How to migrate Unicode UTF-8 CLOB data from Oracle to SQL Server 2017 UTF-?

Tags: migration, sql-server-2017, utf-8, clob

I am currently assisting in a migration effort of this application from Oracle 12c to SQL Server 2017. Initially I just performed table inserts using openquery to Oracle. I discovered that the tables which contained CLOB data could not be migrated using a single table to table insert query otherwise we would end up with dirty data. I am able to do the inserts by dynamically generating a single insert statement per row and running thousands of lines of insert statements. The problem is I've now come across a table which contains over 300k records with CLOB data in them. The one record at a time insert is taking an extremely long time and may at this rate run over 24hrs which is unacceptable.

What is my best option for migrating such a large amount of CLOB data from Oracle? Should I use the bulk tools like BCP, BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET?

**Edit/Update:** I have since learned that my troubles are most likely due to the UTF-8 encoding at the source Oracle system. Both methods I've used for migrating both CLOB and BLOB data have resulted in mismatched rows or missing rows.

UTF-8 has some known issues with SQL Server. The ones in particular I'm dealing with, Linked Server OPENQUERY and SSIS Project deployments, are [both fixed in SQL Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-ver15?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#databaseengine).

Comment: Any reason you're not using SSIS?

Comment: It's not a feature we have used and I'm still fairly new to it.  Is it worth learning it to be able to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes I think it's worth consideration.

Comment: Can you please explain this statement: "_ tables which contained CLOB data could not be migrated using a single table to table insert query otherwise we would end up with dirty data._" Is this an encoding issue? How are you bringing this data over? Linked Server?

Comment: hi @SolomonRutzky. When I performed an INSERT INTO SELECT * from openquery to the oracle database, it appeared that the rows were coming over but the CLOB column had missing data. I didn't have enough time to sit down and figure out why it was doing it so I just moved on.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "missing"? Was it `NULL`? Empty string? All rows like this or just some rows?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I wish I could. Unfortunately I do not have direct access to the systems. And my investigative ability into the environment is hindered for reasons I can't go into here. I have to do a screenshare and direct another dba with access on what to run. Thus it makes investigations difficult.  Since this migration effort is just a one-time use I want to focus on the best solution for the situation. i.e. migrating tables with CLOB data from Oracle into SQL Server.

Comment: Have you considered using [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017) to do this migration for you? Also, are you using Unicode character fields e.g. NVARCHAR (MAX), to hold your CLOB data from Oracle?

Comment: @HandyD That was the first thing I started with. It too has problems with this data conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out - https://www.attunity.com/products/replicate/attunity-replicate-for-microsoft-migration/

"Attunity Replicate for Microsoft Migrations is a special, no cost offering for Microsoft customers to help migrate data from popular databases to the Microsoft Data Platform."

Comment: That's worth a shot but at this time I only have a .edu email and my personal email. The download page only accepts business emails :(

Comment: I have started to look into SSIS and Attunity, any [help here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237487/attunity-connectors-for-ssdt-are-not-showing-in-vs-2017-ssis-toolbox) would be appreciated.