# Attunity Connectors for SSDT are not showing in VS 2017 (SSIS Toolbox)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2017, ssis-2017

I'm trying to add a connection manager using the new Attunity drivers I downloaded but I'm not seeing it as an option.

[This Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-2017) does not list the latest SSDT version (15.x) as one of the compatible versions with the Attunity Connectors  version 5.

Comment: If I recall you have to add those new items into the toolbox. I don't have any screen shots for this as I'm without SSDT at my current gig. However there should be a way through the menu to add those to the toolbox.

Comment: @Zane Wasn't able to find what you are referring to any time I create a New Connection Manager, not only are my Oracle drivers showing, but neither are the Attunity drivers.